# How to hide content table cells

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with a table and when the user click the radio button No the content of the following cells in that row should be visible. And when clicking Yes, the content should be hidden again. There is no difference now.  It works outside the table.

I have tried style="display:table-cell" in a div-tag and in the td-tag - no success.

Picture of the form for the user

[image]

The error message in DevTools is: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'checked')
at yesnoCheck

Picture of error message in DevTools

[image]

```js
function yesnoCheck(var1, var2) {
  if (document.getElementById(var1).checked) {
    document.getElementById(var2).style.display = 'none';
  } else document.getElementById(var2).style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
th {
  background-color: #dddddd
}
```

```html
<h1>Hide input fields based on radio button selection</h1>

<h3>Frame</h3>

Propellers OK?<br />
<input type="radio" name="yesno" id="noCheck" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck('noCheck', 'ifNo');">Yes
<input type="radio" name="yesno" id="noCheck" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck('noCheck', 'ifNo');">No<br>
<div id="ifNo" style="display:none">
  <input type="checkbox" /> Replaced<br /> Date <input type="date" /><br /> Checked by <input type="text" />
</div>

<br /> Frame arms OK?<br />
<input type="radio" name="framearms" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck('framearms', 'framearmsDiv');" id="framearms" />Yes
<input type="radio" name="framearms" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck('framearms', 'framearmsDiv');" id="framearms" />No
<div id="framearmsDiv" style="display:none">
  <input type="checkbox" /> Replaced<br /> Date <input type="date" /><br /> Checked by <input type="text" />
</div>
<br /><br />

<form>
  <table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
      <th>What to do</th>
      <th>OK</th>
      <th>Replaced</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Checked by</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>The propellers, motors, and aircraft body are intact, and there is no sign for collision or loose or broken structures.</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="aftercheckbodyR" id="aftercheckbodyR" value="Yes" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck(aftercheckbodyR, aftercheckbodyDiv);" />Yes
        <input type="radio" name="aftercheckbodyR" id="aftercheckbodyR" value="No" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck(aftercheckbodyR, aftercheckbodyDiv);" />No
      </td>
      <div id="aftercheckbodyDiv" style="display:table-cell">
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="aftercheckbodyC" value="Yes" /></td>
      </div>
      <td><input type="date" id="aftercheckbodyD" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="aftercheckbodyT" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>The temperature of the motors is normal and there are no signs of uneven heating.</td>
      <td> <input type="radio" name="afterchecktempR" value="Yes" />Yes
        <input type="radio" name="afterchecktempR" value="No" />No
      </td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" id="afterchecktempC" value="Yes" /></td>
      <td><input type="date" id="afterchecktempD" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="afterchecktempT" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: ids should be unique

Comment: Thanks, I will work with the IDs.
It is the visible and hide function in the table that does not work.

Comment: I suggest you change the table to use divs like the other questions. That makes the whole thing easier to code and to fill out too

Answer (score 0):

You need

1. Valid HTML - you have divs between the cells
2. Unique IDs.
3. Consistent use of name, tags, values etc.
4. No need to prefix everything with `javascript:`

I strongly recommend you wrap each set in a container, then you do not need inline JS you can just look at the value and use `hidden=value==="Yes"`

```js
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  const hide = tgt.value === "Yes";
  tgt.closest("div").querySelector("div").hidden = hide; // hide the nested div 
})
```

```css
th {
  background-color: #dddddd
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1>Hide input fields based on radio button selection</h1>

  <h2>Frame</h2>
  <div>
    <h3>Propellers OK?</h3>
    <input type="radio" name="yesno" value="Yes">Yes
    <input type="radio" name="yesno" value="No">No<br>
    <div hidden>
      <input type="checkbox" /> Replaced<br /> Date <input type="date" /><br /> Checked by <input type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>Frame arms OK?</h3>
    <input type="radio" name="framearms" value="Yes" />Yes
    <input type="radio" name="framearms" value="No" />No
    <div id="framearmsDiv" hidden>
      <input type="checkbox" /> Replaced<br /> Date <input type="date" /><br /> Checked by <input type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not a element with id 'framearms' that's why it's null

```
<input type="radio" name="framearms" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck('framearms', 'framearmsDiv');" id="framearms" />Yes
```

Comment: When I click the Yes and No buttons, the visible and hide function work for the "Propellers OK?" and the  "Frame arms OK?"  
It is the visible and hide function in the table that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Two issues found in your code

1. <input type="radio" name="aftercheckbodyR" id="aftercheckbodyR" value="Yes" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck(aftercheckbodyR, aftercheckbodyDiv);" >

Quotes are missing for input field as it should be string - id of control 

- <input type="radio" name="aftercheckbodyR" id="aftercheckbodyR" value="Yes" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck('aftercheckbodyR', 'aftercheckbodyDiv');" 

2. In correct HTML - include 'aftercheckbodyDiv' <div> tag inside <td>

<td>
    <div id="aftercheckbodyDiv" style="display:table-cell">
       <input type="checkbox" id="aftercheckbodyC" value="Yes" />
     </div>
</td>
```